# react native flexbox split screen

Tags: react-native, flexbox

i am trying to split the screen using flexbox, but i am not getting the result i desire, here is what i have

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>{/* half of the screen */}</View>

    <View style={{flex: 1}}>{/* the other half */}
        {/*<Swiper>*/}
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>{/* a quarter of the other half */}</View>
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>{/* a quarter of the other half */}</View>
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>{/* a quarter of the other half */}</View>
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>{/* a quarter of the other half */}</View>
        {/*</Swiper>*/}
    </View>
</View>
```

the problem that i am having is that the other half of the screen expands to take the size of the full screen, it is just appended to the first half without taking into consideration that is bounded by the half it exist in

[screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11578812/14655738/573d63a6-068c-11e6-85d3-04b549ecd16b.PNG)

how should i approach this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uhm, so I kind of know what I am doing in React Native now, after over a year of learning.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', flex: 1 }} />

  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Swiper>
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2
        }}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Test</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2
        }}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Test</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2
        }}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    </Swiper>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: you must explain swiper element

Comment: i got you broo. im hang out develop like tinder or something and i saw the swiper element is this . https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper :D right?  
I think we think the same way :D

Answer (score 2):

Try giving `flexDirection: 'row'` style to the outermost view.

Comment: this only changes the orientation which is not what i am looking for, notice in the screenshot i posted, i added some text to one of the quarters and put it in the center, it got trimmed, for some reason it follows the parent's parent restrictions instead of the parent iteslf

Comment: if you put up a sample code to rnplay.org, I'll check it out.

Comment: i am using a react-native-swiper wrapper for the four quads, it cannot run on rnplay

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: https://rnplay.org/apps/DQ2gxA

The basic idea is that you have the amount of columns (8 in this case) as a constant and then you split the available space with your needs. And use `flexDirection: 'row'` with the parent containers.

Comment: i tried your method, it didn't work for my code for some reason, i am using a react-native-swiper wrapper for the four quads, essentially, three quads are always hidden and only one is being displayed, does this affect anything? it shouldn't! take a look at the placement of the text inside one of the quads, it is not in the middle even thoough it's properly flexed http://i.imgur.com/IAU9tdL.png