# how to split entire screen into parts of various sizes in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to React-Native. Please help me with the question. 
I tried the following ways but unable to split the screen vertically..

1. Tried changing height in **percentage**.

   ````
       <View style={{width: '100%', height: 150, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
       <View style={{width: '100%', height: 150, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
       <View style={{width: '100%', height: 150, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
   </View> ```
   ````

2.

[How to divide screen to two parts in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295141/how-to-divide-screen-to-two-parts-in-react-native)

3.

[react native flexbox split screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727473/react-native-flexbox-split-screen)

Comment: Please update your question and provide necessary data , also please explain what you expect from two mentioned link in your question. if you have question about that page also, please ask in the same question page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox).

```js
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanku so much Adam..! it worked..! also I added style={{ height: '100%', }} to the parent component.

Comment: I think that the `height` is pretty much unnecessary in your case. Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.